# Create a dump file from a select

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to create a dump file from the folowing select in nodeJS:

```
SELECT o1.* FROM objects_pool o1 inner join objects_pool o2 on o1.op_id = o2.op_id_object_corpse where o2.op_id_zone_pool = 41
```

I tried:

exec( `'mysql -e "SELECT o1.* FROM objects_pool o1 inner join objects_pool o2 on o1.op_id = o2.op_id_object_corpse where o2.op_id_zone_pool = 41" -u root -pxxxxx dbNAME > FILE_PATH'`

but the only thing I get is a list of results.

Comment: Do you mean `child_process.exec` with your `exec()` call?

Comment: yes, i want to extract only a few rows to put them in another table on another server i wanted to use mysqldump but i can't use it with this select query

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use pipes or redirects from within `child_process.exec`. If you want to specifiy a different output for `child_process.exec` than stdout, you will have to do it by spcifiying it in the options (also see the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)):

```
var fileOut = fs.createWriteStream('FILE_PATH');
child_process.exec('mysql -e "SELECT o1.* FROM objects_pool o1 inner join objects_pool o2 on o1.op_id = o2.op_id_object_corpse where o2.op_id_zone_pool = 41" -u root -pxxxxx dbNAME', {stdio: [undefined, fileOut, undefined]}, function (err) {
  // called when done
  fileOut.end();
});
```

Comment: That documentation is actually one of very few that I can actually understand without bursting a vein in my head. Nodejs is awesome.

Comment: actually i just need to create a dump from a more complex query! and you can use pipes and redirects, i am currently doing it with mysqldump

Comment: That code will dump the output from a command into a file. But indeed, you are able to use redirects and pipes from `child_process.exec()`. I am a bit baffled to be honest. Those are shell features, I wasn't aware of that node starts a command interpreter to spawn child processes.